# R Shiny Queue of Processes

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny-server, shiny

I'm working on a Shiny server that processes large datasets and emails results. We've written code to compute and mail the results, but we would like to implement a queuing system to process each submission in the order received.

I plan on utilizing the Queue class described here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/implementing-a-queue-as-a-reference-class/

**Currently** our flow works like this:

1. A person will input a CSV file and their email into our shiny app.
2. The startServer file observes the submit button, and makes calls to a plotting method (in plotting.R), which plots the data as a PNG, and returns the filename.
3. The returned filename and email are then passed by shinyServer to the mailing method (in mail.R) which mails out the data.

Note: the calls to mail and plotting are not set as "local=TRUE", thus they are in the global environment.

**My idea** is to:

1. Declare a Queue object (q) outside of the startServer method but still in server.R and call q$push(inputtedData, email).
2. From there, the queue object would make the calls to compute and mail the file to the client, and wait until each job is done before moving onto the next.

**The problem** is that I'm not sure how to allow the Queue file to accept asynchronous calls to push new data onto the queue structure. Seeing as startServer is a per-session environment, what must I consider as I implement a shared queue.

Links that I am using for reference:
https://gist.github.com/thesamuel/2450bbee9ef3082e21f68d37b1d40060

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Will `promise` and `future` solve your problem (link: https://rstudio.github.io/promises/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably ways of doing this. Certainly there are some pieces of code written which are designed to allow calling asynchronous code from Shiny apps. See https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/9504798d93e5c50109f8bbaec5abe372 https://gist.github.com/andrewsali/3317e5954459fef2f5fed68d68c1ac92 (both using reactive to update shiny output after asynchronous tasks run) and https://github.com/alexbbrown/mURL (asynchronous HTTP, designed for use in Shiny). Note that these are all somewhat experimental/PoC code, they might help you in patching together a solution, but are unlikely to work out-of-the-box for you.

However, I would suggest that you don't want to use this approach. Your requirements look like this:

1. You have time-consuming jobs you want to run on request or user input.
2. You want to return to the user before the job has completed.
3. Nothing in the web page depends on the completion of the job.

In your place, I would just write to a queue, external to Shiny, in the simplest way possible. For example, append to a file or add a row to a database. Shiny interactivity can then continue immediately. You can set up a whole separate process outside of Shiny, which will read from the file/table, and send an email each time it does so.

In fact, you are lucky that you are sending emails, which can be done completely outside of Shiny, rather than having some need for full (and complicated) async.